# Outlook Ui element, Object reference not set

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I would like to change the text property of an label which I use in an custom Ui-element for Outlook. But I get the dump: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at this line CustomUI.set_lbl_txt = "Text"; . Iam running out of ideas if someone has a clue I would deeply appreciate it :) .

```
    //Main class
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {         
       public Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane mycustomPane;

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
        {
            UI CustomUI = new UI (); //The Ui element I want to customize
            CustomUI.set_lbl_txt = "Text";
        }
    {

    //This is the class of the UI element
    public partial class UI : UserControl
    {      
     public string set_lbl_txt
      {
        get { return lbl_text.Text; }
        set {
                //lbl_text = my label
                lbl_text.Text = value;                    
            }
      }
```

Comment: `lbl_text` in the setter is null ...

Comment: Can you give me further details? Is the setter not right?

Comment: Is the ThisAddIn class a form?

Comment: No, in my understanding it´s the "main class" of an VSTO AddIn, The UI class however is part of a Form.

Comment: @JasperB lbl_text is a reference type (Label) and there's no instance of it.

Comment: UI CustomUI = new UI (); The Label is a part of this class so there should be an instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I seem to have fixed the problem.

The first Problem was that I never (like mrsargent said) Initialized my Form also my setter was wrong so i added an variable and a method to apply my changes.

```
          public string txt_name;

          public void setValues()
          {
             lbl_text.Text = txt_name;
          }

          public string set_lbl_text
          {
             get { return lbl_Task_text.Text; }
             set {
                     this.txt_name = value;                    
                 }
          }
```

ty all for helping!

Comment: would you please accept the answer if it helped you. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a constructor in your UI class?  That error will occur if you don't.  This works for me.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UI CustomUI = new UI();
        CustomUI.set_lbl_txt = "Text";
    }
}

 public partial class UI : UserControl
{
    public UI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string set_lbl_txt
    {
        get { return lbl_text.Text; }
        set
        {
            lbl_text.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```